# In MongoDB, I have a 2 member replicaset. One goes down, and nothing can connect

Tags: c#, mongodb, replicaset

I have a replicaset that consists of 2 servers.  When testing failover, I shut down the primary server.  I expected all clients to start hitting the other server.  Instead, they keep trying to hit the primary and time out.  The secondary never elects itself the primary.

Either I'm configuring the client incorrectly, or a mongo replica set requires three servers to have any failover.  Which one is it?  Here's my configuration.

```
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    Credentials = new[] { credential },
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet,
    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority,
    WaitQueueTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
    MaxConnectionPoolSize = 3000

};

string[] hosts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoServerIpsSemiColonSeparated"].Split(';');
var servers = hosts.Select(x => new MongoServerAddress(x)).ToList();
settings.Servers = servers;
settings.ReplicaSetName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameOfReplicaset"];

Client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

Comment: It's worth directly checking the status of your replicaset, to see the failover has worked or not - don't just trust the client to have switched if possible.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Yup, did that.  The remaining server said secondary and that it could not connect to any other replica set members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a valid behaviour for your scenario.

As per mongo docs a replica set need to be build with minimum of 3 members. As primary fails, then secondary has not a quora to elect himself as a master. Moreover this could lead to harm, just kill secondary and see that primary will step-down, so replica set will be not usable at all.

Add an arbiter to your set up to solve this problem.
[More here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/#arbiter)